# MEF Filter ImportMany

Tags: c#, mef

Let's say that I have the following 3 classes:

```
[Export("Settings",typeof(ISettingsItem)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Settings1Vm {}

[Export("Settings",typeof(ISettingsItem)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Settings2Vm {}

[Export("Settings",typeof(ISettingsItem)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Settings3Vm {}
```

If is possible for example to do this:

```
[Import]
private ISettingsItem SettingEntry{ get; set; }
```

But in a way that this import only takes the export of the Settings2VM class?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the solution was:

```
[Export("Settings",typeof(ISettingsItem)]
[Export("Settings2Vm ",typeof(ISettingsItem)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Settings2Vm {}

[Import("Settings2Vm ", typeof(ISettingsItemVM))]
private Settings2Vm SettingEntry{ get; set; }
```

This way I will always have the same instance.